# how to generate sql like "select a,b from a left join b on (a.id = b.aid and b.aid = 12)" in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

There's a question how to generate sql expression like

```
select a,b from a left join b on (a.id = b.aid and b.aid = 12)
```

in sqlalchemy...

I tried with

```
session.query(a.id, b.id).outerjoin(b, a.id == b.aid and b.aid == 12)
```

but did not got the right result...

is this feasible in sqlalchemy? ?